# Pandas: Drop duplicate values based on a hierarchy

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to drop all duplicates of a product number, retaining only the highest record according to a predefined hierarchy, the values for which are in a separate column.

The hierarchy is seen below:

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
A5
```

A snippet of the overall DataFrame `df` can be seen below.

```
product_num   price_category  
101           A1              
101           A3               
202           A2              
202           A4              
302           A2               
302           A5
303           A5
303           A1
304           A4
304           A3
```

The desired output I'm hoping to achieve is shown below.

```
 product_num   price_category  
    101           A1              
    202           A2              
    302           A2               
    303           A1      
    304           A3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert column `price_category` to [ordered categoricals](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html), so if use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) drop duplicates by hierarchy:

```
c = ['A1','A2','A3','A4','A5']
df['price_category'] = pd.Categorical(df['price_category'], ordered=True, categories=c)

df = df.sort_values(['product_num','price_category']).drop_duplicates('product_num')
print (df)
   product_num price_category
0          101             A1
2          202             A2
4          302             A2
7          303             A1
9          304             A3
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a 2 line answer

```
df = df.sort_values(by = 'price_category')
df = df.drop_duplicates('product_num')
```

First line will output

[image: sorted dataframe]

The repetitions in price_num column is now dropped, giving the required result.